# multi dimensional array filter in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i am trying to filter from multi dimensional array in vue js.

first i am storing response from axios in a variable like

```
fetchUsersDetails() {
        var vm = this;
        axios.get('school/api/user',{headers: getHeader()}).then(response => {
            Vue.set(vm.$data, 'userList', response.data.data)
            //console.log(this.userList)
        })
    },
```

on doing console.log(this.userList) iam getting

```
    0:{
     name:rajesh
     city:dhanbad
     state:jharkhand
     student_session{
      0:{
       class_id:1
       session_id:1
      }
     }
    }
1:{
 name:rohan
 city:dhanbad
 state:jharkhand
 student_session{
  0:{
   class_id:1
   session_id:1
  }
 }
}
 2:{
 name:rahul
 city:dhanbad
 state:jharkhand
 student_session{
  0:{
   class_id:2
   session_id:1
  }
 }
}
 3:{
 name:ramesh
 city:dhanbad
 state:jharkhand
 student_session{
  0:{
   class_id:3
   session_id:1
  }
 }
}
```

and so on...
 now in html

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th style="display: none">Id</th>
    <th>Sl. No.</th>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <th style="display: none">Id</th>
    <th>Sl. No.</th>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr v-for="(studentDetails, index) in filterUserLists">
    <td style="display: none">{{studentDetails.user_token}}</td>
    <td>{{index+1}}</td>
    <td>
        <a @click="showModal(studentDetails)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showModal" >{{studentDetails.first_name}}</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

and i am filtering my userList

```
filterUserLists: function () {
    if(this.userList)
    {
            var list= this.userList
                   .filter(item => item.student_session.class_id==="1" )
    }
    console.log(list)
},
```

but i am getting empty list on my console though in my userList student_session is present with all values

i am new to vue js, so please help me
thankx in advance...

Comment: Looks like your `student_session` is an array. Try `item.student_session[0].class_id`.

Comment: ye student_session is an array 

on using 

item.student_session[0].class_id==1

i am getting 

[Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'class_id' of undefined"

Comment: @wostex plz help i am getting above mentioned error

Comment: This is because your data hasn't arrived at the moment of the DOM mount. In your template use `v-if` and check if your data exists before trying to access it.

Comment: @wostex but i am populating all the users with class_id 1 in var list and then i am displaying it.. but i am not able to get into 2nd array (student_session) using item.student_session[0].class_id or item[0].student_session[0].class_id

Answer (score 1):

you can use computed

```
computed: {
    filterUserLists () {
        var filtered = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.userList.length; i++) {
            if (this.userList[i].student_session.class_id == "1") {
                filtered.push(this.userList[i]);
            }
        }
     return filtered;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be rather a problem with your filter because you try to access the secound array directly.

For me it worked with
`userList.filter(item => item.student_session[0].class_id===1 )`
and
`userList
.filter(item => item.student_session
.filter((item2 =>item2.class_id===1 )) )`

Or just use two loops like everyone does for a two dimensional array.
`for(var i =0; i < userList.length; i++){
  ...
  for(var j=0; j < userList[i].student_session.length; j++){
    if(userList[i].student_session[j].class_id===1){
      ...
    }
  }
}`

If you declared filterUserList unter `methods` you have to use it as function in the `v-for
<tr v-for="(studentDetails, index) in filterUserLists()">`

You try to access the properties `.user_token` and `.first_name` but these are never declared.

Comment: on using userList.filter(item => item.student_session[0].class_id===1 ) i am getting the following error [Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'class_id' of undefined"
 
@Reiner on using var list= this.userList .filter(item => item.student_session .filter((item2 =>item2.class_id===1)) ) iam getting all user list, but class_id of only one user is 1 – rajesh 53 mins ago   

filterUserList under computed

Comment: @ Reiner in userList i am getting array like 0:{ name:rajesh city:dhanbad state:jharkhand student_session{ 0:{ class_id:1 session_id:1 } } } 1:{ name:rajesh city:dhanbad state:jharkhand student_session{ 0:{ class_id:2 session_id:1 } } } 2:{ name:rajesh city:dhanbad state:jharkhand student_session{ 0:{ class_id:3 session_id:1 } } }